# Sphinx 3.0.3 searchd don't see my config

Tags: sphinx

I try ver 3.0.3 (ver 3.0.2 works).
The searchd cannot see sphinx.conf .

```
#indexer --all --config sphinxdata/sphinx.conf
```

creates indexes how it said in config:

```
path = /home/user/sphinx-3.0.3/sphinxdata/indexes/test1
```

Ok. But:

```
# bin/searchd
no config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder.
```

Also tried:

```
#/home/user/sphinx-3.0.3/bin/searchd --config /home/user/sphinx-3.0.3/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf
No config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder.
Both sphinxdata and config file 'sphinxdata/spinx.conf' exists. Using 'sphinxdata' folder.
```

I use Ubuntu16 and Sрhinx 3.0.3 binary.

Answer (score 6):

Right answer (from author Sphinx): Remove the folder sphinxdata!

Comment: Which is in the /home/sphinx-3.3.1/bin directory, the same place as searchd

Answer (score 1):

v3, drasticially changed how it 'looks' for the sphinx.conf file, it no longer varies by distribution for example.

In general would say best to use absolute paths...

```
/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx.conf
```

Comment: I checked absolute paths and corrected my  question.  Indexer works good but searchd don't  controlled. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

```
./searchd --stop
```

while you are in /bin folder
then

DELETE SPHINXDATA FOLDER first thing.

You have to create `/usr/local/sphinx/var/data` and `/usr/local/sphinx/var/log` folders on sphinx 3 and not start `searchd` before indexes created with `indexer --all` setting.
Once all indexes are created - `searchd` can be started otherwise it will continue saying:

```
The searchd cannot see sphinx.conf .
no config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder.
No config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder.
Both sphinxdata and config file 'sphinxdata/spinx.conf' exists. Using 'sphinxdata' folder.
```

And another difference from old Sphinx is - you have to start and to stop it by providing config file path, not only for indexing. If you do not provide - it creates `sphinxdata` folder and you have to stop it without config then, delete that `sphinxdata` folder and start correctly to avoid incorrect setup.

```
RUN such for start/stop:

./searchd --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf

./searchd --stop --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf
```

The same with indexer - provide a full path to config!